# Crystal report - Group Towns by Countries

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have two tables

[image]

With this query i got the results

```
select countries.id, countries.name, Towns.id,Towns.TownName
from
Countries
left outer join Towns on countries.id = towns.countryID
```

[image]

Now i want to group results by country to get something like this on my `CrystalReport`. Is it even possible to make it ?

[image]

Comment: It should be as simple as selecting the [country as a Group Header](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Crystal_Reports_XI.asp?Page=3_2)

Comment: @StuartLC that was fast thanks but i still don't know to set GROUP BY query ;S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you have provided, doing a `GROUP BY` in Sql Server would not be desirable. A Sql `GROUP BY` is generally used to project single scalar values from a list in each group, e.g.

```
SELECT Countries.Name, Count(Towns.Id) AS NumberOfTowns, Sum(Towns.Population) AS TotalPop
FROM Countries
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Towns 
   ON Countries.Id = Towns.CountryID
GROUP BY Countries.Name;
```

Would give results like

```
Name         NumberOfTowns            TotalPop
Bosnia       2                        123456
England      2                        98765
```

by applying the Aggregates `COUNT` and `SUM` to all rows (Towns) in each country.

This isn't going to be useful for your report, as you need to show a list of all towns per country.

What you want instead is to use your current query as-is, and then to apply a Crystal Group Header on `Countries.Name`. Then, in Crystal, remove the `Countries.Name` field from the Details section (since you don't want the country repeated). You'll possibly also want some ordering done in the groups and data - again, I would suggest you do this in Crystal (although an `ORDER BY Countries.Name, Towns.TownName` would also work).

You'll then have a report which resembles your requirement.

Comment: im still strugling with this. Im not that familiar with crystal reports so i got to this point. Can you please take a look on it.  http://pokit.org/get/?00ce6ab725efe00e7f5c9c190ee7de32.jpg  . Is it standard drag and drop procedure or how ?